# how I add view helper in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

### I want to add custom view helper in zend framework like this:

1. I placed in application.ini this code:

   > includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
   >   and create library directory in myproject root
2. create  view helper   TabEntry.php in library directory

   > > class Zend_View_Helper_TabEntry extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
   > >
   > > > public function TabEntry() {
   > > >
   > > > > }
   > > > >         }
3. create another  view helper TabEntries.php in library directory

   > > > > > > class Zend_View_Helper_TabEntries extends Zend_View_Helper_TabEntry {
   > > > > > >
   > > > > > > > > public function TabEntries() {
   > > > > > > > >
   > > > > > > > > > > }
   > > > > > > > > > >                     }
4. when in my phtml use $this->TabEntries() get error
5. in Bootstrap.php I add some code:
   $view->addHelperPath('MyView/Helpers', "library_MyView_Helpers");
   $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
   $viewRenderer->setView($view);

Comment: chouldn'T it be $this->tabEntries() ? :)

Comment: And what kind of error you get?

Comment: this error Class 'Zend_View_Helper_TabEntry' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ZF coding application structure, correct version would be:

In application.ini:

```
resources.view.helperPath.Your_View_Helper = "Your/View/Helper"
```

Then the helpers: (not sure why do you need another abstract class):

```
// library/Your/View/Helper/TabEntry/Abstract.php

class Your_View_Helper_TabEntry_Abstract extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
    public function tabEntry($param1, $param2) {} // note the lower case here
}

// library/Your/View/Helper/TabEntries.php

class Your_View_Helper_TabEntries extends Your_View_Helper_TabEntry_Abstract {
    public function tabEntries($param1, $param2) {...} // note the lower case
}
```

In the view:

```
$this->tabEntries();
```

Important: `call_user_func` and Linux filesystem are case sensitive.

Comment: By doing this I get this error:  Fatal error: Class 'MyView_Helpers_TabEntry' not found in D:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\tab_cms\library\MyView\Helpers\TabEntries.php on line 3

Comment: @Behrang Double check your file names and ensure you are following PEAR naming conventions.

Comment: dear takeshin file names are correct, I'm really confused I want to use only one class in another OOP !!!

Answer (score 0):

Double check the code you have in your bootstrap

> in Bootstrap.php I add some code:
>
> ```
> $view->addHelperPath('MyView/Helpers', "library_MyView_Helpers");
> $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
> $viewRenderer->setView($view);
> ```

Should be more like

```
$view->addHelperPath('My/View/Helpers', "My_View_Helpers");
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
$viewRenderer->setView($view);
```

On my side, I use:

```
// Add path to project view helpers
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->initView();
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->view
    ->addHelperPath('Julien/View/Helper', 'Julien_View_Helper')
    ;
```

and have that kind of class in `Julien/View/Helper/Percent.php`

```
<?php
class Julien_View_Helper_Percent extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function percent ( $percentage ) {
        return $percentage * 100 . '%';
    }
}
```

then calling in the view

```
<?= $this->percent(0.255) ?>
```

will output

```
25.5%
```

and my directory layout looks like

```
project/
    lib/
        Julien/
            View/
                Helper/
                     Percent.php
        Zend/
    modules/
public/
   .htaccess 
   index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend framework/located in `/var/www/html/you`

1) `you/application/views/helpers/<Magic is here>`

2) Put this file called "Stuff.php" in above path

> ```
> <?php
> class Zend_View_Helper_Stuff extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract 
> {
>   public function stuff()
>   {
>     $output = "IK BEN View Helper en DAN????";
>     return htmlspecialchars($output);    
>   }
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

3) Go to you/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml
`<?= $this->stuff(); ?>` :)

4) output will be the $output.

Answer (score 0):

Add helper in zend 3

create helper class Helper.php in module/Admin/src/View/Helper/Helper.php

after that add the following code in:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
class Helper extends AbstractHelper {
    public function test($messages) {
        echo $messages;
    }
}
```

module/Admin(your module name)/config/module.config.php

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

```
'view_helpers' =>[
    'factories' => [
        View\Helper\Helper::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'mainHelper' => View\Helper\Helper::class
    ],
],
```

call on view

```
<?php
$this->mainHelper()->test('Abhishek');
?>
```