# Changing CSS class dependent on page

Tags: php, css, layout

Using Zend, I'm trying to find the most efficient way to call a new CSS class for each page. I would rather not create a new layout for each page. I was curious if I could use a variable to change the class.

In the layout I was going to use:
    `<div id="main" class="<?php echo $header; ?>">`

The CSS looks like:

```
#main {
display:block;
min-width:960px;
}

#main.homeBG {
height:451px;
background:url(../img/images/home_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

#main.toolsBG {
height:451px;
background:url(../img/images/tools_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
```

So there are different BG images for the different pages.

What I am trying to do is change the $header variable in the Controller action for each view.

```
class ToolsController extends ZendExtension_Controller_Action
{
/**
 * Init
 */
public function init()
{
}
/**
 * Default Index Action
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $header = $this->view->('toolsBG');
}
}
```

I know that's wrong, but I'll just use that for my example here.

Would there be a way to accomplish this, or should I just make a separate layout page for each view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not into Zend Framework, but are you trying to set the $header variable to the current page? If so, try using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (yes, ugly) or maybe pass it on as a variable into your view?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to set a view variable from controller, then this is how:

```
//controller
$this->view->header = 'toolsBG';

//view
<div id="main" class="<?php echo $this->header; ?>">
```

But if your action names are self explanatory then you can create a view helper and within that helper, you can return your action name, or an underscore-separated combination of module, controller, action etc.

For info on how to create a view helper, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741556/how-i-add-view-helper-in-zend#answer-3742222)

For info on how to get module, controller, action in view helper, use the following:

```
$request    = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
$module     = $request->getModuleName();
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
$action     = $request->getActionName();
```